# Chome and IE not offering to save password after input type is changed by script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, passwords

I have a form containing:

```
 <input type="password" id="password" />
```

in which I wish to temporarily display some readable text, therefore:

```
$('#password').prop('type', 'text');
```

but when the type is subsequently changed back to password say:

```
$('#password').focus(function () {
    $('#password').prop('type', 'password');
});
```

then when the form is submitted, the '...remember password?' dialog in fails to launch in Chrome and IE (it works in Firefox).

If the initial convert to text type is delayed, e.g.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#password').prop('type', 'text');
}, 1);
```

everything works as required in all browsers.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the browsers are not offering to save the password either as a security measure or as a bug.

A more reliable solution (and one that gets around security restrictions in IE8) is to create a text field immediately afterwards in the DOM which is hidden. When you want to toggle the display, toggle the visibility on both as well as the *name* of the field so that server-side code treats both fields equally.

Below is a simple version of how you could accomplish this:

```
<input type='text' id="thisPasword" name="hello" />
<input type='text' id="thisText" name="helloTmp" style="display:none"/>

function toggle() {
    var both = $("#thisText,#thisPassword"),
        hidden = both.filter(":hidden"),
        visible = both.filter(":visible");

    hidden.attr("name", "hello").val(visible.val()).show();
    visible.attr("name", "helloTmp").hide();    
}
```

My organization has successfully implemented a solution like this one, which worked across all browsers.